# Release NSPipe Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, pipe

Is it necessary to release a NSPipe created writing

`NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];`

?
Actually I do not call `alloc` so theoretically I should not call release...Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you’re right. As usual, the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) apply: if you’ve obtained an object via a method that isn’t NARC (name contains new, alloc, copy, or is retain), then you don’t own that object, hence you don’t release it.